# Facebook Android SDK - search user by phone number

Tags: android, facebook, api, phone-number

I'm having some trouble with the facebook SDK on Android. I would like to search a user by his phone number. For example when I'm on my account on my computer, if I put my friend's phone number in the search field, it gives me his profil, I would like to do exactly the same but programmatically speaking. I thought it would have worked with this :

```
/search?q=0123456789&type=user
```

But it gives me this error (even if I granted all the permissions to my access token) :

```
"message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200
```

Does anyone knows how to achieve this goal ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Searching by phone number isn't (and, afaik, never was) possible via the Graph API. The error you're receiving is not related to this, but because you're apparently not using a user access token when using the `/search` endpoint.

Still, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=<your_user_access_token>
```

Comment: how can we get user details by phone number with facebook api

Comment: Please check Tobi's response above. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31607962/1091026